# MySQL: Query to login using Where AND and OR doesn't work

Tags: mysql, authentication, where-clause

I'm implementing a system login which in database I have this table:

**cat_clients**

```
Id    Name    Rfc        Email            P_Name          P_Email          S_Name          S_Email          T_Name          T_Email
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
1     Rick    RFC2345    rick@email.com    George      george@email.com    Daniel     daniel@email.com      Fred        fre@email.com
2     Mary    RFC2212    mary@email.com    Brad        brad@email.com      Allan      allan@email.com       Edward      edward@email.com
......
.....
.... more
```

So, to login success, User must enter 'Rfc' and any email (Email, P_Email, S_Email and T_Email). User have these emails because are alternative contacts.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * 
FROM cat_clients
WHERE (Email = 'george@email.com' OR P_Email = 'george@email.com' OR S_Email = 'george@email.net' OR T_Email = 'george@email.com') AND Rfc = 'RFC2345';
```

But my Query doesn't work. I hope I explained.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * 
FROM cat_clients
WHERE 'george@email.com' IN (Email, P_Email, S_Email, T_Email) AND
      Rfc = 'RFC2345';
```